# neo4j find all paths between nodes. Trek & mountaineering routing

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I start to learn neo4j. I am using the graph

http://neo4j.com/graphgist/b1f6439d-2904-4fcf-8017-8c83d57ef20b#listing_category=sports-and-recreation

and I have a problem. I do not know how to get all the connections from `Darjeeling` to `Sandakphu`. All queries return invalid input or no rows.

Could anyone see how should be build correct query?

1)This is correct

```
MATCH (p:peak{name:'Sandakphu'})-[r:twowheeler*]-(t:town{name:'Rimbik'}) return distinct(r)
```

What's wrong with this one if I want all routes

```
MATCH (p:peak{name:'Sandakphu'})-[r:*]-(t:town{name:'Darjeeling'}) return distinct(r)
```

2)
This is correct

```
MATCH (a:village { name: 'Sirikhola' }),(b:village{ name: 'Gurdum' }) MATCH (a)-[r]->(b) RETURN r
```

With this

```
MATCH (a:village { name: 'Sirikhola' }),(b:town{ name: 'Darjeeling' }) MATCH (a)-[r]->(b) RETURN r
```

i have no rows

Comment: Please post some sample code which explains what you have done till now and make the question more clear.

Comment: is i t better now?;]

Answer (score 3):

In the second case, there appears to be no path of length 1 between Sirikhola and Darjeeling, and so the query returns nothing. Try putting a reasonable upper bound for the max hops:

```
MATCH (a:village{name:'Sirikhola'})-[r*..5]-(t:town{name:'Darjeeling'}) 
return r
```

The first query should also work (I've added an upper bound instead of leaving it unconstrained):

```
MATCH (p:peak{name:'Sandakphu'})-[r*..5]-(t:town{name:'Darjeeling'}) 
return r
```

BTW you can consider using [allShortestPaths](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#_all_shortest_paths)